# refs not working in Vue typescript for calling methods in child component

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I have a problem at calling a function in a child component Im using typescript

```
<notification ref="notification"></notification>
<button @click="$refs.notification.show()"></button>
```

how can I fix this ?
I get this error, my code runs but doesn't work the way it should

> Object is of type 'unknown'

code of the notification component

```
<script lang="ts">
export default{
methods:{
  show(){
    console.log('working');
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share the code of `notification` component

Answer (score 1):

You should `defineExpose` in `notification` component :

```html
<script setup>

 function show(){
       console.log('working');
   }

defineExpose({
  show
})
</script>
```

or in normal script  :

```html
<script lang="ts">
export default{
methods:{
  show(){
       console.log('working');
      }
  },
  expose: ['show'],
}
</script>
```