# Ref doesn't work in separate HTML template

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs3

i am facing this (maybe stupid) issue with my simple project in Vue. When i split template/code in single files ref stop working and i've undefined value in HTML template.

**This works**:

map.component.vue

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
    import { ref } from 'vue';
    var mapUrl = ref('');
    mapUrl.value = 'https://myUrl/myImg.png';
</script>

<template>
    <img class="map" :src="mapUrl" alt="Location map">
</template>
```

**This Not**:

map.component.vue

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import './map.component'
</script>

<template src="./map.component.html"></template>
```

map.component.ts

```js
import { ref } from 'vue';
var mapUrl = ref('');
mapUrl.value = 'https://myUrl/myImg.png';
```

map.component.html

```html
<img class="map" :src="mapUrl" alt="Location map">
```

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73933303/8172857

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Can you please suite this for my case? I am very new in Vue. Really appreaciate

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the composition API you cannot outsource your JS code if you use it in setup: https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html

If you want to outsource your JS code you need to declare the component:

- https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-spec.html#script
- https://vuejs.org/api/general.html#definecomponent

Inside the `defineComponent` you the can hook into the setup method: https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-setup.html